# Matrix representation of an operator relative to the canonical basis

Tags: linear-algebra

A linear operator $A$ is defined with:

$$A\left(\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ b & c \end{bmatrix}\right) = (a-b-c) + (a+2c)x+(a+2b+3c)x^2 $$

How to determine matrix $A$ in relation to the canonical basis?

Comment: What is $x$? It's always better to sketch what you tried.

Comment: @pitariver $x$ is what is called an "indeterminate" : $A$ maps the vector space of $2 \times 2$ symmetric matrices on the vector space of 'formal" polynomials with degree $\leq 2$.

Answer (score 1):

A basis for the space of symmetric matrices is given by
$$\mathcal{B}=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}\right\}=\{\color{red}{\mathbf{m_1}}, \color{red}{\mathbf{m_2}}, \color{red}{\mathbf{m_3}} \}.$$ 
Now find what the transformation does to basis elements.
\begin{align*}
A\left(\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}\right) & =1+x+x^2\\
A\left(\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}\right) & =-1+2x^2\\
A\left(\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}\right) & =-1+2x+3x^2\\
\end{align*}
Can you find the matrix now?

---

**Additional explanation**

**Your confusion** about multiplying a $3 \times 3$ matrix with a $2 \times 2$ matrix stems from the fact that you are treating $A(\mathbf{m})$ as multiplication of the matrix $[A]$ with the matrix $\mathbf{m}$. Just like we do with $A\mathbf{x}$. But that's where your interpretation is incorrect.

So when we want to represent the action of $A$ on the matrix 
$\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\b&c\end{bmatrix}$ as matrix multiplication, what you should think of is the **coordinate vector** for this matrix in terms of the basis $\mathcal{B}$. Since
$$\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\b&c\end{bmatrix}=a\color{red}{\mathbf{m_1}}+b\color{red}{\mathbf{m_2}}+c\color{red}{\mathbf{m_3}}.$$ 
The **coordinate vector** for the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\b&c\end{bmatrix}$ in the basis $\mathcal{B}$ is $\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{bmatrix}$. So when we say $A(\mathbf{m})$ we can think of it as multiplying the matrix $[A]$ with the *coordinate vector of $\mathbf{m}$* with respect to basis $\mathcal{B}$.

Also assuming we are using the standard basis for $P_2$ as $\mathcal{C}=\{1,x,x^2\}$, we can identify the polynomials
$$a+bx+cx^2 \leftrightarrow \begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{bmatrix}$$

The three equations stated above can now be viewed as:
\begin{align*}
A\left(\color{red}{\mathbf{m_1}}\right) & =[A]_{\mathcal{B}}\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}\\
A\left(\color{red}{\mathbf{m_2}}\right) &  =[A]_{\mathcal{B}}\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}-1\\0\\2\end{bmatrix}\\
A\left(\color{red}{\mathbf{m_3}}\right) & =[A]_{\mathcal{B}}\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}-1\\2\\3\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
Then the matrix representation can be given by
$$[A]=\begin{bmatrix}\uparrow & \uparrow & \uparrow\\ A(\color{red}{\mathbf{m_1}})& A(\color{red}{\mathbf{m_2}}) & A(\color{red}{\mathbf{m_3}})\\ \downarrow & \downarrow & \downarrow\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1&-1&-1\\1&0&2\\1&2&3\end{bmatrix}$$